# How can i get id of row inserted on Postgres 9.5 UPSERT

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I do not know if this is a bug, a feature or a problem in the documentation.

Let's say I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tags(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  value TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  creation_time TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

If you run `INSERT INTO tags(value) VALUES('a') RETURNING id;` you will get the id of the newly inserted value **BUT**:

Running it again with 
`INSERT INTO tags(value) VALUES('a') ON CONFLICT(value) DO NOTHING RETURNING id` will give **NO** id, that means either is a BUG or the documentation is wrong because documentation http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html states:

```
INSERT INTO table_name [ AS alias ] [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
    { DEFAULT VALUES | VALUES ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) [, ...] | query }
    [ ON CONFLICT [ conflict_target ] conflict_action ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

This basically means you **CAN** use both, has anyone find this same problem and solved it?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is right and there is no bug. You overlooked this part:

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return value(s) based on each row ***actually* inserted** (**or updated**, if an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause was used)

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

If you specify `DO NOTHING` then the statement will neither insert nor update anything and thus it can't return an ID.